# Excel VBA single quote in a string

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make one of my variables equal to the following:

```
Dim Quote as string
Quote =  "Letter Size 11 x 17""
```

I need the single quote/inch symbol in the text but i do not know how to make VBA recognize it without giving me and error saying i have to end quote it.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these.  It seems to do what you want (depending on where you want the ":

```
Sub test()
Dim Quote As String

Quote = "Letter Size 11 x 17"""
Debug.Print Quote

Quote = "Letter Size 11"" x 17"""
Debug.Print Quote
End Sub
```

Comment: I think that downvote comes from the fact that someone thinks you are repeating one of the most upvoted answer in the duplicate link. Well, there are no many way to answer this question and your answer doens't add anything new.

Comment: Fair enough, and duly noted.

Comment: @HumanlyRespectable Most likely downvoted because a simple search on this site or Google would have yielded you the answer.